# Maximum number of rows in a sqlite database ? (to querying efficiently)

Tags: sqlite

I've Developed a data logger system with C , that read data from sensors and save the info taken in SQLite database.

Now my purpose is to reporting data from SQLite weekly.

In a period of one week about 900000 rows (each row has 4 columns) stored in SQLite table .

My main question: is it possible to query between this number of rows ? (900000 row)

And second problem is usage of RAM and CPU when query between 900000 rows !

Comment: What happended when you tried it?

Comment: i tested it with my machine and it works good . and all of my queries successfully done . but i want to know that does any machine can query between this number of rows easily ?

Comment: Only you can measure how much memory and CPU your program needs.

Comment: Can i know what is the largest number of rows that i queried between them without any problem ? (for example a query with 3 where clauses and order , between 800000 rows ) @CL.

Comment: That depends on the database schema, the actual data, and your hardware and software. Only you can measure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the complexity of your query.

A simple select statement with a where clause is usually computed with constant memory requirements. The same applies to a select count(*) from table. The following query requires a constant amount of memory and only needs to scan the data once.

```
select count(*) from table;
```

However, if the query needs extra storage to compute the query, then it will need memory and/or disk space. For example, this query:

```
select count(distinct atr) from table
```

would require as much memory as different values of atr there.

So in summary, for queries that read the entire table,
it all depends on how much memory is needed to compute the query. As a rule of thumb: simple selections require constant memory. Group by's and order-by require to sort the data. Joins --depends on the dbms-- might need a lot of space.

Comment: Thanks to answer :)